# OS X command line app text interface

Tags: macos, unix, text, command-line, binary

I am writing a command line binary app for OS X in Objective-C.  I would like to create an app like the "top" single screen utility rather than spitting out linear, scrolling output to the console.

Is there an API/framework for creating a screen UI with exact placement of text?  This would be similar to old DOS apps where one could PrintAt x, y, "text"

Thanks,
Don

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean by a UI with exact placement of text, but have you looked into nurses/curses?

Comment: As an example, [`htop`](http://hisham.hm/htop/) uses [ncurses](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. This framework is called [`ncurses`](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/), and is available on most UNIX systems (including Mac OS X).